# Modifying Mountmellick's Irish Stout

Tags: stout, kits, spices, holiday

I have a can of this, but want to do something different with it and have it ready for the holidays.

My first thought was pumpkin, but I couldn't figure out from reading how or when to put it in; and most people found it didn't change flavor at all, it's about the spices you add...again, not sure how much or when.

I also read of people adding lactose and making a cream stout. Or oatmeal stout. Etc.

Unfortunately searching I just find full on recipes, but nothing hacking a kit.

I'd really like some help and advice on what I can do, to "jazz this up".

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it cannot be answered by a specific verifiable answer without subjectivity and matters of personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

My advice to you is just to experiment and have fun with it. For spices, add them to the primary or late in the boil along with your finishing hops. If you want a "pumpkin spice" ale, check the spices in your favorite pie recipe and note the proportions of spice used. For your largest-dose spice, don't use more than 1 tbl per 5 gallons (less is safer, but then you might not get much flavor), and add the others in proportion to that.

I would also add: be very careful with clove. A little goes a very long way. ;-)

Comment: Do you mean 1tbsp per spice, or total?

Comment: Max 1 tbl per. So for example (I have never done a pumpkin spice beer, not my thing) I pull up a random pie recipe that calls for 1/2 tbl cinnamon, 1/4 tbl ginger, and 1 tsp vanilla extract, I would double that to 1 tbl cinnamon, 1/2 tbl ginger, 2 tsp vanilla. Actually, I would scrap the extract and use two vanilla beans (most brew stores carry them).  For an example of a spice beer I have done: 1 tbl rosemary, 1 tbl catnip, 5 whole cloves (to a 5 gallon batch).